# HW kbd failed to set (null) as keyboard focus iOS Xamarin.iOS 10.2.1.5

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin.ios, uitextfield

I have looked at other thread on same topic but couldn't get any answers there and hence created a new thread.

I am running into subjected error. It started when I upgraded my iPad to iOS 9.3.5 and it happens only on UITextField field. Here are logs but not able to find the root cause. This is occurring in Xamarin.iOS 10.2.1.5 which is latest and greatest.

```
Nov 26 13:16:09 rb-iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Nov 26 13:16:09 rb-iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: HW kbd: Failed to set (null) as keyboard focus
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 219: No such process
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 219: No such process
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Unable to get short BSD proc info for 219: No such process
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad SpringBoard[46] <Warning>: Application 'UIKitApplication:com.safetytracker.app[0xbad8]' exited voluntarily.
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad UserEventAgent[23] <Warning>: 89823664133: id=com.safetytracker.app pid=219, state=0
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad mobile_installation_proxy[194] <Error>: 0x1f197000 handle_connection: Could not receive request from host.
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124[218] <Warning>: 1 +0.000000 sec [00da/0a0b]: error: ::read ( 6, 0x64dd7c, 1024 ) => 0 err = No such file or directory (0x00000002)
Nov 26 13:16:10 rb-iPad com.apple.debugserver-@(#)PROGRAM:debugserver  PROJECT:debugserver-340.3.124 [218] <Warning>: Exiting.
```

Has anyone faced the same issue? Not sure what am I going wrong.

Comment: Did you get any solution for this issue?

Comment: This was an issue at code level. After thorough debug, found the issue. I had additional logic in the keyboard event. NSNotificationCenter.DefaultCenter.AddObserver(UIKeyboard.DidShowNotification, KeyBoardUpNotification);

Answer (score 1):

This turned out to be an issue with code. But surprisingly code was working fine until I upgraded to latest build.

Lesson learnt, debug the code as you never know what part of code will start failing after you upgrade the Xamarin.